# How to combine the keys and values of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have an array of key/value pairs in PHP:

```
array( 'foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'qux' );
```

What's the simplest way to transform this to an array that looks like the following?

```
array( 'foo=bar', 'baz=qux' );
```

i.e.

```
array( 0 => 'foo=bar', 1 => 'baz=qux');
```

In perl, I'd do something like

```
map { "$_=$hash{$_}" } keys %hash
```

Is there something like this in the [panoply of array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) in PHP? Nothing I looked at seemed like a convenient solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function parameterize_array($array) {
    $out = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
        $out[] = "$key=$value";
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: I accept this answer because it is straightforward, and how I ended up solving my problem. I am disappointed there is no way to do it in a single expression, avoiding the need for the temporary $out variable.

Comment: If you're a Perl user, this will be just one of the many, many disappointments you will encounter in the course of your experience with PHP.

Comment: @chaos Yeah, life is rough, and php is readable.
@nohat Although this doesn't "transform" the array as your question stipulates. It makes a new one. "Panoply of array functions"? Giggle.

Comment: @GZipp: Yeah, `$foo = isset($bar['baz']) ? $bar['baz'] : 'qxx'` is so much more readable than `$foo = $bar[baz] || 'qxx'`.  Can't imagine what I was thinking.

Comment: Well, the "?:" operator was added to php so perlish coders could put everything on one line; I'd have thought you'd like that feature.

Comment: I like the conditional operator fine.  What I'm not as fond of is having crippled, brain-damaged logical OR and logical AND operators.

Answer (score 20):

Another option for this problem: On PHP 5.3+ you can use `array_map()` with a closure (you can do this with PHP prior 5.2, but the code will get quite messy!).

> "Oh, but on `array_map()`you only get the value!".

Yeah, that's right, but we can map more than one array! :)

```
$arr = array( 'foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'qux' );
$result = array_map(function($k, $v){
    return "$k=$v";
}, array_keys($arr), array_values($arr));
```

Comment: In PHP 8+, it's even simpler, thanks to the new `fn` syntax:  
`$result = array_map(fn($k, $v) => "$k=$v", array_keys($arr), array_values($arr));`

Answer (score 5):

A "curious" way to do it =P

```
// using '::' as a temporary separator, could be anything provided
// it doesn't exist elsewhere in the array
$test = split( '::', urldecode( http_build_query( $test, '', '::' ) ) );
```

Comment: I came up with same solution, but I'm "curious" )) about encode/decode process if its monosemantic. I've tried to use it for quick arrangement of query conditions in ORM, but for some reason doubt about data safety when urlencode/urldecode.

Answer (score 0):

chaos' answer is nice and straightfoward. For a more general sense though, you might have missed the `array_map()` function which is what you alluded to with your `map { "$_=$hash{$_}" } keys %hash` example.

Comment: array_map(), it seems, only gives you the array's values

Comment: Unfortunately, the strict equivalent code in PHP below 5.3 is a `create_function()`-using abomination.

Comment: Ah, nohat, if you need the keys then you might be able to use `array_walk()` instead (though that modifies the array in-place instead of returning a new array).