# remove all but last comma

Tags: php, list, while-loop, each, substr

i have the following code:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {

    $implode_keys_values = @"$key=$value,";



    echo"$implode_keys_values";
}
```

which ends up echoing out `xxxx=xxxx,xxxx=xxxx,xxxx=xxxx,xxxx=xxxx,`
depending on how many keys/values there are.

how do I take this dynamically changing string and remove the very last comma on it?

keep in mind:

```
$implode_keys_values = substr($implode_keys_values,0,-1);
```

will not work, it will take out all the commas.

Comment: `$value` contains `,` ??

Comment: oh yeah, just updated it. It does indeed have a , after $key=$value

Comment: Related: [How to combine the keys and values of an array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413589/how-to-combine-the-keys-and-values-of-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, this would be a better way to implement `implode()`:

```
$data = array();
while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {
   $data[] = "$key=$value";
}
echo implode(",",$data);
```

Comment: you updated your answer first to use`[]` and you pointed out I had a `,` after `$value` which got the question rolling. Thank you very much, your a lifesaver!

Answer (score 3):

`rtrim($implode_keys_values, ",")` would cut trailing commas.

You can learn more about [rtrim here at the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

```
$implode_keys_values = "";
while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {

    $implode_keys_values .= @"$key=$value,";
}
echo rtrim($implode_keys_values, ",");
```

Comment: I only need the last `,` removed. I still want the other ones intact.

Comment: `while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {

    $implode_keys_values = @"$key=$value,";
 $implode_keys_values = rtrim($implode_keys_values, ",");

 
 echo"$implode_keys_values";` echos `key=valuekey=valuekey=value`

when it should be: `key=value,key=value,key=value`

Comment: put the rtrim outside the loop - at the very end

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a function built in for that if the data in the array is not too complex (works for the xxxxxx values you have, can break with others):

```
echo http_build_query($arr, '', ',');
```

See [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query).

Another alternative is using iterators and checking if the current iteration is the last one. The [`CachingIterator::hasNext()`](http://php.net/cachingiterator.hasnext) method is helpful for that:

```
$it = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($arr));
foreach($it as $key => $value) {
    echo $key, '=', $value, $it->hasNext() ? ',' : '';
}
```

This variant does work with any data.