# Join php object key-value

Tags: php

I have this object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [transaction] => sale
    [type] => apartment
    [city] => washington
    [rooms] => 1
)
```

I want to join keys and values to get a string:

`transaction-sale/type-apartment/city-washington/rooms-1`

I managed to do it with a `foreach()` and a empty var:

```
$data = "";
foreach($obj as $key => $o):
    $data = $data."/$key-$o";
endforeach;
```

But this seems ugly, did I miss any core PHP function that can easy do this?

Comment: `$data = "";
foreach($obj as $key => $o):
    $data .= $key.'-'.$o.'/';
endforeach;$data = trim('/',$data); echo $data;`

Comment: Try this once and let me know

Comment: There's no core functions for that. What you have is enough.

Comment: how about: `$result = explode('::', urldecode(http_build_query($data, '', '/')  ));` SOURCE: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1413660/2649661

Comment: Theres really not a one single core function, you have to use multiple functions together to achieve this.. You are better off using `foreach` sort of like what you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the purpose of this function, but this also has the side benefit of URL encoding the variables and values for use in a URL:

```
$data = str_replace('=', '-', http_build_query($object, null, '/'));
```

To add a second approach, though this does not URL encode:

```
$data = implode('/', array_map(function($k, $v){
                                   return "$k-$v";
                               },
                               array_keys((array)$object), (array)$object));
```

Comment: Ahhh, `array_map` always seem to forget this function. Nice single-liner.

Answer (score 1):

You might not want the first or last `/`, perhaps its better like this.

```
foreach($o as $k => $v){
  $a[] = "$k-$v";
}

echo implode('/', $a);
```

---

```
function foo($obj){
  foreach($o as $k => $v){ // this will fail if there are any more -public- variables declared in the class.
    $a[] = "$k-$v";
  }

  return implode('/', $a);
}

echo foo($yourobject);
```

---

```
class foo{
  $transaction = 'sale';
  $type = 'apartment';
  $city = 'washington';
  $rooms = 1;

  function __tostring(){ // or a normal method name.
    foreach($self as $key => $value){ // this will fail if there are more variables declared in this class.
      $a[] = "$key-$value";
    }

    return implode('/', $a);
  }

  function bar(){ // will always work.
    return "transaction-{$self->transaction}/type-{$self->type}/city-{$self->city}/rooms-$self->rooms";
  }
}

echo $myobj;
echo $myobj->bar();
```

---

Or like this (or any above variation of it):

```
$s = "" // must be done to avoid PHP strict errors, code will function anyways.
foreach($o as $k => $v){
  $s .= "$k-$v/";
}
echo substr($s, 0, -1);
```

Overall, I prefer the first method but since you have an object it might be useful to actually do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all : http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Gets you the object's members as an associative array, then : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

That would give :

```
php > $o = new stdClass();
php > $o->transaction = "buy";
php > $o->type="house";
php > $o->city="Paris";
php > $o->rooms=2;
php > $a = get_object_vars($o);
```

Then I'd use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php :

```
php > function walk(&$value, $key) {
php { $value = "$key-$value";
php { }
php > array_walk($a, 'walk');
php > var_export(array_values($a));
array (
  0 => 'transaction-buy',
  1 => 'type-house',
  2 => 'city-Paris',
  3 => 'rooms-2',
)
```

EDIT :
thanks for the comment :

```
php > echo implode("/", array_values($a));
transaction-buy/type-house/city-Paris/rooms-2
```

Comment: Then you might want to `implode` on `/`.